# Sorting Javascript associative array values in descending order

Tags: javascript

I have the following method that gets the word frequency based on some input text:

```
function getWordFrequency(lowerCaseArray) {
    var wordFrequency = {};
    $.each(lowerCaseArray, function(ix, word) {
        // skip empty results
        if (!word.length) {
        return;
        }
        // add word to wordFrequency
        if (!wordFrequency[word]) {
        wordFrequency[word] = 0;
        } 
        wordFrequency[word]++;
    });
    return wordFrequency;
}
```

However, I would like to return the frequency of words on a descending order, i.e.

```
cats => 20
dogs => 19
frog => 17
humans => 10
```

Currently, my algorithm returns in the order in which the input words appear.

Comment: You can't sort objects. You can create an array of objects and sort it by using `Array.prototype.sort` method.

Comment: Another way to say it: there is no guarantee of the order of keys in an object

Comment: Object.keys(words).map(key => ( {key: key, count: words[key]} )).sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return an array of objects if you want ordering. Properties of an object do not have a guaranteed order.

```
var obj = getWordFrequency(words);
var array = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
     return {word: key, count: obj[key]};
});
array.sort(function (a,b){ return b.count - a.count});
```

Typed from my phone, untested, order of a and b may need to be reversed